# VBA, doc.getElementsByClassName() works in debug mode not in run mode

Tags: excel, vba

I am using below code in vba,

```
Set results = Doc.getElementsByClassName("a-size-large a-color-price olpOfferPrice a-text-bold")

If results.Length > 0 Then
```

but the length only gives >1 in debug mode not in run mode, I checked the site and gives have having class above mentioned, but strangly works in debug mode that too line by line debug mode and does not work in run mode.

Thanks
DJ

Comment: Please show the full code. Especially where `Doc` comes from. You must give the browser time to load the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're loading the document, but it isn't complete before you try to inspect the document. When you run in debug mode, the document has time to complete loading. The best way to force VBA to wait for the document to load completely is to open the URL/Document in Synchronous mode. You'll also want to check that the document request returned a valid HTTP status code.

If your document source is valid XML/XHTML, then you can get a document object directly from the XMLHttpRequest, but I'm assuming you have plain old HTML.

You need to be aware that the XMLHttpRequest will retrieve the HTML content of the page, but it will not load or run any of the supporting scripts/css, so if any of those scripts *would* have generated dynamic HTML content, then it won't be present in the HTML document.

```
Sub Test()

  Const URL As String = "http://stackoverflow.com"
  Const CLASS_NAME As String = "row-fluid"

  'The getElementsByClassName method is unavailable under some/all IE versions?
  'It seems to need to be strongly typed as MSHTML.HTMLDocument
  'You'll need to Add a reference to Microsoft HTML Object Libarary
  Dim oDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument

  Dim results As Object

  With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHttp")
    .Open "GET", "http://www.microsoft.com", False
    .send
    'Check the response is valid
    If .Status = 200 Then
      Set oDoc = CreateObject("htmlfile")
      oDoc.body.innerHTML = .responseText
      Set results = oDoc.getElementsByClassName(CLASS_NAME)
    End If
  End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your code is trying to fetch data from website, use the below method to fetch data. 
This code will wait until HTML data is fetched before executing your IF condition. 
(Reference: [Code Snippet from this website](http://officetricks.com/download-html-table-to-excel/))

```
'Replace the URL of the webpage that you want to download
Web_URL = "http://websitename.com"

'Create HTMLFile Object
Set HTML_Content = CreateObject("htmlfile")

'Get the WebPage Content to HTMLFile Object
With CreateObject("msxml2.xmlhttp")
    .Open "GET", Web_URL, False
    .send
    HTML_Content.Body.Innerhtml = .responseText
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the page is loaded before trying to access DOM elements by checking the `ReadyState` and `Busy` properties of IE:

```
Sub Foo()

    Const READYSTATE_COMPLETE As Integer = 4

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    IE.Navigate "http://www.stackoverflow.com"

    '// The important bit:
    While IE.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE Or IE.Busy
        DoEvents
    Wend

    '// Rest of your code, presumably something like:
    Set Doc = IE.Document

    Set results = Doc.getElementsByClassName("a-size-large a-color-price olpOfferPrice a-text-bold")

    If results.Length > 0 Then

    '// Rest of code here .....
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks ! i have done similiar way, also the but it sometime gives 0 length sometime not. here it goes. IE.navigate "http://www.amazon.com/gp/offer-listing/" & A_S.Cells(Row, 11).Value & "/ref=olp_sss_new?ie=UTF8&f_freeShipping=true&condition=new"
       ' IE.navigate "http://www.amazon.com/gp/offer-listing/" & A_S.Cells(Row, 11).Value & "/ref=olp_sss_new?ie=UTF8&condition=new&shipPromoFilter=1"
       ' Do While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
       '' DoEvents
       ' Loop
       ' Set Doc = IE.document

Comment: I would enter a breakpoint just before you set the collection and check that all your variables have the expected values. The error could actually be somewhere else, for example you could be activating a sheet or workbook when stepping through manually that doesn't happen in 'live' execution.