# The data necessary to complete this operation is not available error

Tags: json, excel, vba

I have a VBA code that pulls in a parses JSON data. The issues I'm having is that usually when I open the workbook and run the macro, I get an error "the data necessary to complete this operation is not available" on the line "Set json = ParseJson(http.responseText)". If I debug using F8, the error usually clears and the macro runs fine. Any advice on how to fix this issue would be greatly appreciated.

```
Public Sub exceljson()

Dim http As Object, json As Object, i As Integer
Dim WB As Workbook
Dim sWHSE  As String
Dim sDate  As String
Dim EDate  As String
Dim eNumber  As String

Set WB = Application.ThisWorkbook

    Application.StatusBar = "Please wait - Loading data ..."
'    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

sWHSE = WB.Sheets("Control").Range("B25")
sDate = WB.Sheets("Control").Range("B38")
EDate = WB.Sheets("Control").Range("B17")
eNumber = WB.Sheets("Control").Range("U39")

Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

http.Open "GET", "https://afttransshipmenthub-eu.aka.amazon.com/inbound/getTransferManifestsByDateAndSourceWarehouse/?startDate=" & sDate & "&endDate=" & EDate & "&warehouseId=" & sWHSE & "&_=" & eNumber & ", False"

http.Send

Set json = ParseJson(http.responseText)

i = 2

For Each Item In json

WB.Sheets("AFT Pull").Cells(i, 1).Value = Item("amazonShipmentReferenceId")

WB.Sheets("AFT Pull").Cells(i, 2).Value = Item("sourceWarehouseId")

WB.Sheets("AFT Pull").Cells(i, 3).Value = Item("destinationWarehouseId")

WB.Sheets("AFT Pull").Cells(i, 4).Value = Item("departureDateUtc")

WB.Sheets("AFT Pull").Cells(i, 5).Value = Item("yardArrivalTimeUtc")

WB.Sheets("AFT Pull").Cells(i, 6).Value = Item("plannedArrivalTimeUtc")

WB.Sheets("AFT Pull").Cells(i, 7).Value = Item("sealId")

WB.Sheets("AFT Pull").Cells(i, 8).Value = Item("trailerId")

WB.Sheets("AFT Pull").Cells(i, 9).Value = Item("transferStatus")

WB.Sheets("AFT Pull").Cells(i, 10).Value = Item("receiveDateUTC")

WB.Sheets("AFT Pull").Cells(i, 11).Value = Item("receivedByUserId")

WB.Sheets("AFT Pull").Cells(i, 12).Value = Item("reconciledByUserId")

WB.Sheets("AFT Pull").Cells(i, 13).Value = Item("priorityScore")

WB.Sheets("AFT Pull").Cells(i, 14).Value = Item("stowByDateUTC")

WB.Sheets("AFT Pull").Cells(i, 15).Value = Item("dockAppointmentId")

WB.Sheets("AFT Pull").Cells(i, 16).Value = Item("dockAppointmentTimeUtc")

WB.Sheets("AFT Pull").Cells(i, 17).Value = Item("numberOfPallets")

WB.Sheets("AFT Pull").Cells(i, 18).Value = Item("numberOfSingleAsinPallets")

WB.Sheets("AFT Pull").Cells(i, 19).Value = Item("numberOfCases")

WB.Sheets("AFT Pull").Cells(i, 20).Value = Item("numberOfTotes")

WB.Sheets("AFT Pull").Cells(i, 21).Value = Item("numberOfItems")

WB.Sheets("AFT Pull").Cells(i, 22).Value = Item("numberOfReactiveItems")

WB.Sheets("AFT Pull").Cells(i, 23).Value = Item("percentageOfReactiveItems")

i = i + 1


    Next

    Application.StatusBar = False
'    Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBA, doc.getElementsByClassName() works in debug mode not in run mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34703810/vba-doc-getelementsbyclassname-works-in-debug-mode-not-in-run-mode)

Comment: Is that solution still going to work if it's JSON data. I tried using the first example and I'm getting multiple error.

Comment: If `.responseText` returns a text it should work. You do not have to copy the exact code. What the answer in the duplicate shows you, is that you have to check if you already got a response/ if the response is valid. If you use the Debugger, you will be slow enough to load the required data in time.

Comment: Sorry for asking, but how would I include the Set json = ParseJson(http.responseText) element in the example in the link. I'm very new to VBA so any help would be appreciated

Comment: Put `Option Explicit` at the top of the module. Declare all variables. Edit the question to add code for `ParseJson`. To simplify for potential responders, hardcode values for sWHSE, sDate, EDate and eNumber. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: ^^ Yes please provide actual test values.

Comment: Your False param should also not be part of the string in the send line. It should be URL, False at the end - where URL is the "string".